# Dynamically Allocated 2D Array EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime, runtime-error

I'm in the early stages of my program and right now I'm simply trying to initialize a 2D array to hold all dashes but I keep getting a ECX_BAD_ACCESS error. My code seems to work with a square array (ex: 5x5 or 6x6) but if I do 10 by 5 I get the error.

```
void readMatrix(char **twoDarray, int &rows, int &cols)
{

std::cout << "Enter number of rows for board";
std::cin >> rows;
std::cout << "Enter number of columns for board";
std::cin >> cols;


//dynamic 2D array initialization
twoDarray = new char*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    twoDarray[i] = new char[rows];

//set elements of array to dashes
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
        twoDarray[i][j] = '-';
        }

//printing the array
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
    std::cout << "  " << std::endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        std::cout << twoDarray[i][j] << "  ";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first for-loop should go from 0 to #rows, not #cols. Also, in the body of that same loop allocate cols, not rows.